# Word to describe an email missing an attachment

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

Have you ever sent an email, intending to attach something and referring to it in the email, but without actually attaching? I'm wondering if there is a word or words to describe:

1. The email itself. e.g. 'I just sent a ????? email'
2. The act of sending such an email. e.g. 'I just ?????ed'

Any proposed word(s) could/should encapsulate concepts of incompleteness or emptiness and/or fact that email was sent prematurely.

I'm not thinking about emails that should have multiple attachments but are incomplete. It's really those simple, '1 attachment' emails.

UPDATE: Playing on another meaning of 'attached', I thought that an email without an attachment could be considered to be 'unattached'. Some words which came up when looking for synonyms were 'single', 'unwed' and 'bachelor'. I don't think any of these are quite right, but hopefully they may inspire others....

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote. If I can improve or clarify the question, please advise.

Comment: *A naked email?* I just *bare bottomed* it? *A phantom attachment*?

Comment: I dislike the silly sentence structure of "Ever blah blah blah?" It is very annoying and confusing. The grammar is unusual, abnormal and unusable as well. "Have you ever .... ?" - that is the better way of saying it.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - your 'dislike' is my call to action and I have edited my post accordingly. I trust that, in time, you can come to forgive my brief descent into a casual style.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Got issues? :(

Comment: @bib I'm not sure about 'naked'. Perhaps 'empty' or 'gutless' might work. I like 'phantom' to describe the missing attachment though.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is no singular word for the phenomena, but you could say it was *sans attachment*. I just sent an email sans attachment.

Comment: Just for fun: a geemail? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gee

Answer (score 1):

"Attachmentless."

Or, you could simply say "E-mail without the intended attachment." There's not exactly a thing for which we've needed an English word.

Answer (score 1):

I might use a compound adjective for the 'I just sent a ????? email' situation:

> 'I just sent you an **empty-shell** email'

And for the 'I just ?????ed' situation, I might say this:

> 'I just **ghost-emailed** you'

...but I'm not aware of a standard form for announcing such mistakes. The most common form of acknowledgment used in intra-office email messages at my workplace is simply a follow-up email message with the attached document included as intended, and with a single line of message text along the lines of:

> This time with the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought. Playing on the ( to me at least ) recent appearance of the phrase ' my bad ' which I take to mean the acceptance of responsibility for an error, I propose ' my b@d '. This could be taken to describe an error in composing or sending an email. In a similar vein, to describe the problem email itself I propose ' efail ' or ' ef@il'.